# Should we try a community check-in on Meta?

Tags: discussion, community

The RPG SE has a [yearly tradition](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-check-in) of posting a community check-in in their meta.

As taken from their [2021 post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11437/64190):

> We, the elected moderators, wanted to take a minute to check in and
> see how the community feels things are going on the site.
>
> This community check-in has been done for the last three years
> (ignoring 2020), and it was very helpful. As such, we'd like to share
> our thoughts and also get your feedback on what is going well and what
> we could improve.

Is there interest trying a check-in for GDSE?

From what I understand, the check-in is intended to foster communication from all parts of the community so this question is directed both toward moderators & non-moderators.

Comment: Looks like your proposal has gained some interest. What do you think the next step should be?

Comment: @Vaillancourt The two take-aways I read are: 1) community is interested & 2) doesn't need to be mod driven. With that in mind, my thoughts were to post something similar to the RPG.SE check-in & see where it goes. Alternatively, we could do another meta post about how to shape the check-in, but for a first time I think it's better to put something together & learn as we go.

Comment: I think we could go ahead with the real thing too! I'm looking forward to read your next meta post!

Answer (score 6):

*This is a personal opinion, and I did not discuss an answer to this question with the other mods.*

---

Yes, I think it would be an interesting exercise.

Answer (score 4):

I'm posting another answer to not mess up with the votes of the "yes" answer because this one here is more like a comment than anything else. *This is a personal opinion, and I did not discuss an answer to this question with the other mods.*

---

A few things to note (emphasis mine):

> **We, the elected moderators**, wanted to take a minute to check in and see how the community feels things are going on the site.

I have a small issue with this statement, as in this case, the proposal has been brought up by an active-non-mod-community member (Pikalek). Thus I don't think the effort needs to be necessarily lead by moderators, although if it is the wish of you or the community, I think we could lead the effort. (In any case, you'll get support from the moderators (I speak for myself, so it's at least *one* moderator :P).)

I think I tend to "just do what needs to be fixed" when I see it (e.g. I post stuff here on meta when I think something should be improved, batch update tags, etc.). I'm not doing this because I'm a mod, I have done this even before I was elected, I just do it because I'm a user of the site. So I don't think this would benefit me *as a mod*; I really see it as an opportunity for community members to get a ball rolling, moderator or not.

Comment: Speaking as an RPG.SE user: yeah, there's no particular reason this needs to be moderator driven. It just happens to be a tradition that was started and then maintained by moderators. :)

Comment: That makes sense!